# cts search returning false results for 'unfiltered' when 'punctuation-sensitive' is passed in element-value-query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I will give an example to replicate the issue.

Assume I have inserted the below `XML` file in Documents DB of `MarkLogic`.

```
<root>
  <name>(publishe name)</name>
</root>
```

I am running the below cts query.

```
cts:search(
  doc(),
  cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('name'), 'publishe name',('case-insensitive', 'punctuation-sensitive', 'diacritic-sensitive')),
  'unfiltered'
)
```

Above query is returning me the above XML even I am passing the `punctuation-sensitive` option.

Please help me to figure out why it's returning the above XML?

Is there in anything wrong in the above `cts search query`?

**Note:** for `filtered` option it's working fine as I am not getting the empty sequence.

**I am using MarkLogic 8**

Answer (score 5):

MarkLogic can only resolve punctuation-sensitive value queries accurately from the indexes alone if they are exact: case-, whitespace-, diacritic-, and punctuation-sensitive. Since your query is case-insensitive it cannot be resolved from the indexes.

xdmp:plan can be used to see what query is being sent to the indexes.

Comment: If I pass `exact` then also getting the document!!

Comment: Using `exact` works as expected for me, e.g. not getting the doc. Check to see if you have the latest patch release of MarkLogic 8, upgrade if possible, and try again.